# How to add rewrite rule for external php file

Tags: rewrite-rules

My permalinks set to post-name.
I have a php file named 'user-messages.php' in my theme directory.
I want to include this php file for this "http://www.example.com/user/messages/" url and if url pattern like "http://www.example.com/user/messages/username/" i need to access this username string in user-messages.php file.

But there is a possible conflict.

```
add_rewrite_tag( '%user%', '([^&]+)' );
add_rewrite_rule('^user/([^/]*)/?','index.php?user=$matches[1]','top');
```

I'm using this rewrite rule for pretty urls. I restricted 'messages' username from registration. So i just need to exclude 'messages' string from my rewrite rule for preventing conflict.
How can i do these. Thanks